# Firebase stored key is wrapped inside Optional(\" \") when doing a nested write

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

No longer a question now. I re-edit this to explain what happened:

I did a nested write like this

```
let key: String!
key = "foo"
let dict = ["Zoes": "7th Street"]
ref.child("/\(key)/shops").setValue(dict)
```

This results in key of "foo" becoming: `"Optional(\"foo\")"` as a String stored in firebase.

So I thought since key is declared as implicitly unwrap, it would just unwrap in the string interpolation. But turned out the string was not forced unwrapped during string interpolation, that's why it's got "Optional" written. It's not a firebase issue now, it's just how String interpolation works in Swift.

Comment: You get the "Optional(x)" string when you use `String(describing:)` or string interpolation with an optional value that you haven't unwrapped.

Comment: You are right, the optional is declared implicitly unwrapped but in string interpolation, it's still an optional. Problem solved. Thank you!

Comment: I marked to close as a "tiny or typographical error". But I actually thing this is more common than that, so: can you write your solution up into an answer (and accept it once the system allows you to)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hold up a sec guys. I ran the exact code from this question and it does NOT write Optional(\"foo\")" to firebase as a key. It simply writes *foo* (with that code, why would it write optional anyway?). I copied and pasted that code. Even observing the ref that contains foo and printing the snapshot does not print an optional value. I think there's more at play here unless I am totally misunderstanding the question.